# unity tap mobile issue

Tags: mobile, unity-game-engine, tap

I have simple scene when player taps, the ball changes directions by 90 degress;
My code works but it is not perfect, mainly issue is "tap" detecting

needed to use `Coroutine` to make pause between taps, but pause of `0.25sec` is to big and response time is slow in some cases, but if try to reduce pause time it runs code so fast that it no longer differ taps;
I've tried also with `touch.phase == began` and `touch.phase.Stationary` but this also didn't work

I want to achieve effect when you tap, it changes direction once, even if you hold it.

Does anybody have better solution of detecting taps?

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;


public class playerController : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed = 2f;
public float tapPauseTime = .25f;
Rigidbody rb;
bool timerOn;
bool goingRight;


void Awake(){

    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    timerOn = false;
    goingRight = false;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{

    if (Input.touchCount == 1 && !timerOn && !goingRight) {

            rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
            rb.velocity = new Vector3 (speed, 0, 0);
            timerOn = true;
            goingRight = true;
            StartCoroutine(TapPause());
        }

    if(Input.touchCount == 1 && !timerOn && goingRight)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(0,0,speed);
            timerOn=true;
            goingRight = false;
            StartCoroutine(TapPause());
        }


}

IEnumerator TapPause(){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(tapPauseTime);
    timerOn = false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you care about is a single touch event (i.e. no multitouch), all the mouse handlers in `Input` mimic the first touch.  Therefore, you can use `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` to find out when there has been a touch.  This fucntion will only return true the frame that a mouse press (or in your case, a touch) occurs, and won't return true again until the button has been released and pressed again.  You could replace the `Input.touchCount == 1` in your if statements with `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` to try this.